# CActiveDataProvider doesnt give selected columns

Tags: php, yii, cactivedataprovider

```
    $criteria->select = 't.*,count(business_unit.id) as TotalBusinessUnits,count(users.id) as TotalUsers ,count(positions.id) as TotalPositions, count(skills.id) as TotalSkills , users.first_name , users.last_name, count(question_bank.id) as TotalQuestions';

    $criteria->condition = "`t`.status = '1'";
    $criteria->group = 't.id';
    $criteria->order = 'created DESC';
    $criteria->join = " inner join users on users.company_id = `t`.id";
    $criteria->join .= " left join business_unit on business_unit.company_id = `t`.id";
    $criteria->join .= " left join billingdetails on billingdetails.company_id = `t`.id";
    $criteria->join .= " left join positions on positions.company_id = `t`.id";
    $criteria->join .= " left join skills on skills.company_id = `t`.id";
    $criteria->join .= " left join question_bank on question_bank.company_id = `t`.id";
```

It works fine and get all columns which I select.
But when I pass it in CActiveDataProvider it gets only `this` attributes.

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination' =>  $pages
    ));
```

How I select all columns?

Comment: Have you got those column names listed as public variables on your model ? add `public $TotalBusinessUnits;`in that model and see if you can get that value.

Comment: can you ellaborate it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yii if you are using `as` for sql, it needs a public variable to store the value in.

add all your custom column names as public variables on the model and all should be dandy.

so if you have  `$criteria->select = 't.*,count(business_unit.id) as TotalBusinessUnits`, this will create the corresponding sql . but Yii does not recognise `TotalBusinessUnits` as a valid column on the table.

So if you add `public $TotalBusinessUnits;` in your model Yii has a place to store this value.

Also you should then add `TotalBusinessUnits` to your safe attributes rule so that Yii knows it safe to fetch.

```
public $TotalBusinessUnits;

public function rules(){
    return array(
        // your rules
        array('TotalBusinessUnits','safe'),
    );
}

public function search(){
    $criteria->select = 't.*,count(business_unit.id) as TotalBusinessUnits';
    // your criteria
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```